# How to make BitSet to be not simplified [JAVA]

Tags: java, bit, bitset

I am using BitSet to represent possible hours where lectures are filled in, the case is that when you put to *false* the corner bits, they are simplified, this means that they are not anymore in the BitSet. How can I ask BitSet to not simplify?

To make my explanation clearer this is the code:

```
   for(Map.Entry<GrupAssig, BitSet> entry : bitsetPerGrup.entrySet()){

            BitSet bitset = entry.getValue();

            //n franges per dia
            int numFranges = UnitatDocent.getNumFranges();
            int indexDia = this.dia.id() * numFranges;

            bitset.clear(indexDia, indexDia+numFranges);
     }
```

Imagine that the bitset has 60 bits by default, and numFranges=12 and this.dia.id()=4. This would make the last twelve bits set to 0. The result I get is:

`111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

But if this.dia.id()=3 I get:

`11111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000011111111111`

And you can print the BitSet this way:

```
    public static void printBitset(BitSet b) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for( int i = 0; i < b.length();  i++ )
        {
            s.append( b.get( i ) == true ? 1 : 0 );
        }

        System.out.println( s );
    }
```

Which demonstrates what I am saying.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by corner bits?  The ones at the range extremes?  What do you mean by simplify?

Comment: Why do you care about the implementation details?  It doesn't make any difference to the results of the methods you can call.

Comment: Yes, I refer to the range extremes. By simplifying I mean that they are erased, given a bitset of size 60 bits, if you set the first ten bits to false, they are not anymore in the set. But if you set the middle bits to false, they stay there.

Comment: Louis, I thought that too, but if you do what I said (setting the ten first bits to false, for example) and the you do:

``bitset.get(0)`` you will get true, and this is not what should happend for what I need.

Comment: Posting your code would help.  One thing I can say is that the length() method may not do what you think it will do because it's based off of the BitSet's cardinality.  In other words, length will look for a 1 at the greatest index to determine length.  If all bits are set to false, [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length()) will return 0.

Comment: @Marc43 that shouldn't be true.  Please show the code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Marc43 You still aren't showing enough code to demonstrate the issue. You mention "the result I get is", but you aren't showing the code that produces that result. If your question is just about how BitSet works, simplify the code to something that just uses BitSet and no other classes and demonstrates the behavior that is causing difficulty for you.

Comment: One option is to set the bit which is one more than the maximum. You can drop this when you print it.  Another option is you store separately how many bits are applicable. There is no attribute in BitSet which records what you want otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the documentation for BitSet.length:

```
length()
Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one.
```

If you need to print out a certain number of bits (e.g. 60) then use a constant instead of ".length()" for your loop. You can call ".get(index)" on any index regardless of the length and it will give you the result for that bit.

For instance the following code produces "0000011000":

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitSet bits = new BitSet();
        bits.set(5);
        bits.set(6);
        StringBuilder bitString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            bitString.append(bits.get(i) ? "1" : "0");
        }
        System.out.println(bitString.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Then imagine that the problem happens for the first bits, this would not work

Comment: I worked pretty heavily with the BitSet class a few years ago, and I don't believe that this problem exists for the first bits. If you think it does, please show a simple example that demonstrates this.